# while greater than negative number not working

Tags: c++, for-loop, while-loop

I have a very trivial piece of code that basically needs to count down from a certain number, and use that count as an index to an array.

```
auto bigSize = BigArray.size() - 1;

while(bigSize > -1) {
   auto thing = arr[bigSize ];
   bigSize--;
}
```

However the code never seems to hit anything inside the loop. I've also tried with a `for` loop:

```
auto bigSize = BigArray.size() - 1;

for(int i = bigSize ; i >= 0 && i < bigSize ; --i) {
   auto thing = arr[i];
}
```

I feel like I'm doing something incorrect, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: does `BigArray.size()` maybe return a `unsigned`? Then `bigSize` would be `unsigned` too and it will never get zero (no matter how often you decrement it)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: In the `while` loop you never modify `bigSize`, how would the condition ever become false?

Comment: This is one of the problems with `auto` -- it hides what type your code is using and sometimes that really matters.

Comment: btw you wouldnt even encounter the problem if your loop had the correct condition: `while (bigSize > 0)`, you don't want to create an array with 0 elements, do you?

Comment: @tobi303 I'm using bigSize to look at the `index` of an array. It means `0` will be the first element... So I do want to make sure I get to `0`

Comment: @TheGeekZn well, my comment was triggered by a misread, just forget about it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while(bigSize > -1) {
   auto thing = arr[bigSize ];
   bigSize--;
}
```

This will never stop. `bigSize` is `unsigned` which means it can't contain negative values. The moment `bigSize` is 0 and you try to decrement it it becomes `std::numeric_limits<type>::max()`. (underflow, not negative) So it'll keep on looping.

Either change your condition or make `bigSize` explicitly an `int`.

Comment: This is correct. I had to cast the size to an int before the loop worked. Thanks for the input! I come from a C# background so this was strange.

Comment: Unsigned integer types don't underflow, they wrap around (or, more precisely, they represent the given number by choosing the representative of its equivalence class in Z mod 2^NumBits that lies in [0,2^NumBits-1]).

Comment: @Baummitaugen Correct, didn't find the correct wording, feel free to edit.

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure I can without conflicting with your intend. I tend to get somewhat "mathy" on this topic (probably overly so for an audience like OP); I would love to rewrite a sentence like *"it can't contain negative values"* to something more precise in the eyes of the modulus arithmetic the unsigned types implement, but again, that would substantially alter the spirit of your answer. I'll leave the choice how technical your answer should be to you.

Answer (score 0):

std::*Container*.size() always returns an unsigned number. An unsigned number will always be greater than a negative number, even if you underflow.